# Batch - setting a variable via IF statement in FOR loop "stuck"

Tags: variables, batch-file, if-statement, for-loop

I'm working on this lil' script that reads columns from the input file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "tokens=2,3,4,5,7,8,9,12,14" %%a IN ('type %1') do (
    set event="NULLA"
    echo %event% - %%h
    if "%%h"=="i" ( set event=FELTOLTES )
    echo %event% - %%h
    if "%%h"=="o" ( set event=LETOLTES )
    echo %event% - %%h
    if "%%h"=="d" ( set event=TORLES )
    echo %event% - %%h  
    echo ---------------------
}
```

However, if I run it, the %event% variable in ALL steps (even the first one, before the `if "%%h"=="i"`), and all rows of the input file is "TORLES", which is defined in the last IF statement:

```
TORLES - i
TORLES - i
TORLES - d
TORLES - i  
TORLES - d
TORLES - d
TORLES - o
TORLES - d
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Tried adding-removing quotation marks around the IF statements, but yielded no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "tokens=2,3,4,5,7,8,9,12,14" %%a IN ('type %1') do (
    set event="NULLA"
    echo !event! - %%h
    if "%%h"=="i" ( set event=FELTOLTES )
    echo !event! - %%h
    if "%%h"=="o" ( set event=LETOLTES )
    echo !event! - %%h
    if "%%h"=="d" ( set event=TORLES )
    echo !event! - %%h

    echo ---------------------
)
```

When you use delayed expansion and try to set/access variables in brackets context you need to access it with `!` instead of `%`

Comment: Holy crap, it worked. Can you explain why is this? Sound really counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: @LordZozzy - here's some explanation and examples - http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html  .With `%..%` the value is expanded\replaced during the reading of the script and everything in brackets is taken for one-line expression.With delayed expansion and `!..!` the expression is replaces\expanded during execution and if there are any changes in variable value they are taken into account.